# How can I get value from one function in another function in Django, views()

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views, django-templates

Hello I am new to Django
I want to get latitude and longitude from myview1 function to myview function so that I can Post that values and put into the relevant code.
PLease Can anyone guide me regarding this?

```
def my_view1(request):  
    
    latitude='latitude'
    longitude='longitude'
    context = {'latitude':latitude, 'longitude':longitude}
    my_view(context)
    return (context)

@csrf_exempt
@require_http_methods(["POST"])
def my_view(request,context):
    if request.method == "POST":
        
        # value_data=(my_view1(data=request.POST))
        value_data=my_view1().objects.all()
        latitude = request.POST.get(value_data['latitude'])
        longitude = request.POST.get(value_data['longitude'])


        # In this example I am reading a file with (time, x, y) as dimensions
        xarr = xr.open_rasterio('/home/shaheer07/New Rasters/image_factors.tif')

        # Slice one of the bands
        img = xarr[0, :, :] 

        #Use the .sel() method to retrieve the value of the nearest cell close to your POI
        pixel_value = img.sel(x=latitude, y=longitude, method="nearest")    

        image = '/home/shaheer07/New Rasters/image_factors.tif'
        with rasterio.open(image) as f:
            # Load metadata
            meta = f.meta
            
            # Use the transform in the metadata and your coordinates
            rowcol = rasterio.transform.rowcol(meta['transform'], xs=latitude, ys=longitude, zs=None)

            y = rowcol[0]
            x = rowcol[1]

            # Load specific pixel only using a window
            window = Window(x,y,1,1)
            raster_values = f.read(window=window)
        return JsonResponse(pixel_value,raster_values, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    else:
        return JsonResponse('Nothing')
```

Comment: my_view1 is not a view. It's not returning an HttpResponse object.

Comment: Can you clarify what you intend? Is it to ask the user for a latitude and longitude, then return a JSONresponse based on his answer?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Django session:

```
def view_1(request):
     request.session['key'] = value

def view_2(request):
     value = request.session['key']
```